# Excel Linest function problem

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vsto

I'm calling Excel Linest() function in C# using excel interop assembly.
I'm providing arrays of type "double" to known x's and known y's but I want to provide 3 variables to known x's. So my X array looks like this: double[8,3]. When I input these arrays to the excel Linest() function, it gives me an error. But, when I input an array of size 3X3 (square matrix) instead of 8X3, it succeeds and gives me some values in the output. So, how do I give multi variate inputs to X variable that do not have a square matrix structure?

Answer (score 1):

I used a 2-dimensional array for known y's as well. So, now my 2 arrays look like these:

```
X: double[8,3] 
Y: double[8,1]
```

This solved the issue for me. There's absolutely no help/documentation/samples for using excel interop functions in C# or any other .NET language.